# Не могу понять проблему засвеченной станции

Tags: сеть

[image: Проблема: а — скрытой станции; б — засвеченной станции]
Если станция B начнет передавать данные, она повлияет на сигнал станции A, разве нет?

Comment: В действительности такая передача создала бы помехи только в зоне от
станции B до станции A, где в данный момент не ведется прием.

Comment: Принимаемый сигнал на станции может быть очень слабым, возможно, в миллион раз слабее излучаемого. В действительности имеет
значение интерференция на приемнике, а не на передатчике.